# generate 100 10-digit random numbers and save to database

Tags: php, mysql, random

This is a pretty simple function yet it keeps giving me errors. Im writing a script to generate 100 10-digit random numbers but I keep having this error: "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'rand(1111111111, 9999999999)'` at line 1.

This is my code

```
<?php
$cxn = new mysqli("localhost", "CJroot", "password", "random");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) { 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO random (random) VALUES 'rand(1111111111, 9999999999)'";
    if(!mysqli_query($cxn,$sql)) {
        die("Error: ".mysqli_error($cxn));
    }
}

/* close connection */
$cxn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `'rand` well, yeah. You need to generate the numbers first, then insert using a variable for it.

Comment: tried that, same error

Answer (score 2):

you need to concat your string like so.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO random (random) VALUES '" . rand(1111111111, 9999999999) . "'";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error that MySQL is complaining about (in your SQL statement) is missing parens around the values list. This is invalid:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES 'foo'
```

Should be

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ( 'foo' )
                       ^       ^
```

Once you get over that hump, the value enclosed in single quotes is interpreted as a *string literal*. In the example code, `'rand(11111,99999)'` is a literal, a string of characters. It's not a reference to a function.

---

If we want to use the MySQL `RAND()` function, we could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO random (random) VALUES ( FLOOR(1000000000 + RAND() * 9000000000) )
```

We can execute that 100 times, or, it would be more efficient to write SELECT statement that returns 100 rows, and insert 100 rows in a single insert.

Or:

```
INSERT INTO random (random) VALUES 
 ( FLOOR(1000000000 + RAND() * 9000000000) )
,( FLOOR(1000000000 + RAND() * 9000000000) )
,( FLOOR(1000000000 + RAND() * 9000000000) ) 
, ...
,( FLOOR(1000000000 + RAND() * 9000000000) )
```

---

In terms of database performance, it is usually more efficient to run a single INSERT statement that inserts 100 rows, than it is to execute 100 individual insert statements. Processing RBAR (row by agonizing row) can be excruciatingly slow.

If there's a need for a loop, if we insert four rows at time, we need only need to go through the loop 25 times. And that's 75% fewer statements we need to execute.

We can specify the SQL text to be executed just one time, outside of the loop, and then just repeatedly execute that same SQL

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO random (random) VALUES"
     . " ( FLOOR(1000000000 + RAND() * 9000000000) )"
     . ",( FLOOR(1000000000 + RAND() * 9000000000) )"
     . ",( FLOOR(1000000000 + RAND() * 9000000000) )"
     . ",( FLOOR(1000000000 + RAND() * 9000000000) )";

for ($i=0; $i < 25; $i++) { 
  if(!mysqli_query($cxn,$sql)) {
    die("Error: ".mysqli_error($cxn));
  }
}
```

Comment: The examples in my answer generate a value `BETWEEN POWER(10,9) AND POWER(10,10)-1`.  (1,000,000,000 and 9,999,999,999). If you want range 1,111,111,111 through 9,999,999,999,  replace the literal `1000000000` with `1111111111` and replace `9000000000` with `8888888889`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it direct with MySQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO random (random) 
SELECT CAST( (RAND()*(9999999999-1111111111)) AS UNSIGNED)  + 1111111111;
```

or for 100 rows:

```
INSERT INTO random (random)
SELECT  CAST( (RAND()*(9999999999-1111111111)) AS UNSIGNED)  + 1111111111 AS random FROM (
SELECT 0 AS h UNION SELECT 1  UNION SELECT 2  UNION SELECT 3  UNION SELECT 4  UNION SELECT 5  UNION SELECT 6  UNION SELECT 7  UNION SELECT 8  UNION SELECT 9 
) h
CROSS JOIN
( SELECT 0 AS l UNION SELECT 1  UNION SELECT 2  UNION SELECT 3  UNION SELECT 4  UNION SELECT 5  UNION SELECT 6  UNION SELECT 7  UNION SELECT 8  UNION SELECT 9 ) l;
```

Comment: but i need to loop the function so it adds 100 random numbers at once

Comment: i have add a sample direct for 100 rows in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
<?php
$cxn = new mysqli("localhost", "CJroot", "password", "random");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO random (random) VALUES"
     . " ( FLOOR(1000000000 + RAND() * 9000000000) )"
     . ",( FLOOR(1000000000 + RAND() * 9000000000) )"
     . ",( FLOOR(1000000000 + RAND() * 9000000000) )"
     . ",( FLOOR(1000000000 + RAND() * 9000000000) )";

for ($i=0; $i < 25; $i++) { 
  if(!mysqli_query($cxn,$sql)) {
    die("Error: ".mysqli_error($cxn));
  }
}
$cxn->close();
?>
```